# Binding Radio Button IsChecked to object's current array of element's state

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am developing a small utility using C#/WPF/MVVM which would allow to set the input state of a controller we are using for testing. The communication between the app I am developing and the hardware/our web service communication to the hardware is only one way, meaning that the app will only be able to **set** the state of the inputs, but not **get** the states.

Another point to mention is that some types are already defined for this in some other parts of our solution, which are all in F#. To do my app, I am currently using C#. So I did a `Unit` class to wrap around the `LocalControllerTypes.LocalController` type defined in F#, containing a lot of needed information.

In order to do that, I have an `enum` enumerating the `InputState` possible (currently there is `Active` or `Normal`, but that list could potentially grow with time). Also, the number of inputs present on each unit type is different (some have 2, some have 4, some have more), so I have an `ItemControl` binded on the selected unit's array of `Inputs`, which unfortunately only contains the Name of the input which I have to display. The unit has 2 other properties related to the inputs it has, `InputWriters`, which is an array of a type which is used to send the command to the hardware/web service communicating with that hardware, and `InputStates`, which is an array of `InputState` for each input it has, as last set in the app (since we can't get the state from the hardware).

Now I would like to bind the `IsChecked` property of the radio buttons (which is what I define as `ItemTemplate` of the `ItemsControl`) to the `InputState` of the currently `SelectedUnit` (in my ViewModel). **The problem I am having**, is that I would somehow need to know the radio button is for which index of the `SelectedUnit`'s `Inputs` array, in order to get the item at the same index for the `SelectedUnit`'s `InputStates` property.

Is there any way to achieve this?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
            ...
            <ItemsControl  Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedUnit.LocalControllerInfo.Inputs}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Margin="10" FontSize="15" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockNormalBase}" Text="{Binding InputName}"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <RadioButton Margin="10" Foreground="White" Content="Normal"
                                             IsChecked="{Binding Path=?,
                                                                Converter={StaticResource inputToBoolConverter},
                                                                ConverterParameter=?}"/>
                                <RadioButton Margin="10" Foreground="White" Content="Active"
                                             IsChecked="{Binding Path=?,
                                                                Converter={StaticResource inputToBoolConverter},
                                                                ConverterParameter=?}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            ...
```

Unit.cs:

```
public class Unit : BindableObject
{
    public enum InputState
    {
        Normal,
        Active
    }

    private LocalControllerTypes.LocalController _localControllerInfo;
    private LocalControllerTypes.ArduinoInjector[] _arduinoInjector;
    private WebWriter.WebWriter[] _inputWriters;
    private SNMPNetworkSwitchConnection.SNMPNetworkSwitchConnection _networkSwitchConnection;
    private InputState[] _inputStates;
    private bool _isUnitConnected;

    public Unit(LocalControllerTypes.LocalController localControllerInfo,
        LocalControllerTypes.ArduinoInjector[] arduinoInjector,
        WebWriter.WebWriter[] inputWriters,
        SNMPNetworkSwitchConnection.SNMPNetworkSwitchConnection networkSwitchConnection)
    {
        _localControllerInfo = localControllerInfo;
        _arduinoInjector = arduinoInjector;
        _inputWriters = inputWriters;
        _networkSwitchConnection = networkSwitchConnection;
        // This assumption might not always be true, but there is no way for now to get the input state
        _inputStates = Enumerable.Repeat(InputState.Normal, _inputWriters.Length).ToArray();
        // This assumption might not always be true, but there is no way for now to get the connection state
        _isUnitConnected = true;
    }

    public LocalControllerTypes.LocalController LocalControllerInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _localControllerInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_localControllerInfo != value)
            {
                _localControllerInfo = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public LocalControllerTypes.ArduinoInjector[] ArduinoInjectors
    {
        get
        {
            return _arduinoInjector;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_arduinoInjector != value)
            {
                _arduinoInjector = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public WebWriter.WebWriter[] InputWriters
    {
        get
        {
            return _inputWriters;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_inputWriters != value)
            {
                _inputWriters = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public SNMPNetworkSwitchConnection.SNMPNetworkSwitchConnection NetworkSwitchConnection
    {
        get
        {
            return _networkSwitchConnection;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_networkSwitchConnection != value)
            {
                _networkSwitchConnection = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public InputState[] InputStates
    {
        get
        {
            return _inputStates;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_inputStates != value)
            {
                _inputStates = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsUnitConnected
    {
        get
        {
            return _isUnitConnected;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_isUnitConnected != value)
            {
                _isUnitConnected = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainViewModel.cs:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Unit _selectedUnit;
    private ObservableCollection<Unit> _units;
    private string _reader1RawCardData;
    private string _reader2RawCardData;
    private int _reader1BitsCount;
    private int _reader2BitsCount;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MainViewModel(IUnitStore unitStore)
    {
        UnitStore = unitStore;

        // We could use directly the unitstore instead of creating another container and binding on that, but
        // not doing so will allow us to add unit filtering further down the road
        _units = new ObservableCollection<Unit>(unitStore.Units);
        _selectedUnit = _units.First();

        _reader1RawCardData = "";
        _reader2RawCardData = "";
        _reader1BitsCount = 0;
        _reader2BitsCount = 0;
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertName = "")
    {
        var temp = PropertyChanged;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertName));
        }
    }

    protected void RefreshUnitStore(object obj)
    {
        UnitStore.UpdateStore();
        Units = new ObservableCollection<Unit>(UnitStore.Units);
        SelectedUnit = Units.First();
    }

    protected void SendReaderCardSwipe(object obj)
    {
        int unitReaderNumber = (int)obj;
        IPAddress arduinoIp = SelectedUnit.LocalControllerInfo.Readers[unitReaderNumber - 1].InjectorIp;
        int injectorNumber = SelectedUnit.LocalControllerInfo.Readers[unitReaderNumber - 1].InjectorNumber;
        string serviceUrl = SelectedUnit.ArduinoInjectors.Where(injector => injector.Ip.Equals(arduinoIp)).First().Url;

        InjectorInterface.CardSwipe<IPAddress>(serviceUrl, arduinoIp, injectorNumber, Reader1BitsCount, Reader1RawCardData);
    }

    protected void UpdateSelectedUnitConnectionState(object obj)
    {
        ((INetworkConnection.INetworkConnection)SelectedUnit.NetworkSwitchConnection).SetConnection(SelectedUnit.IsUnitConnected);
    }

    public IUnitStore UnitStore
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public Unit SelectedUnit
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedUnit;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedUnit != value)
            {
                _selectedUnit = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Unit> Units
    {
        get
        {
            return _units;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_units != value)
            {
                _units = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string Reader1RawCardData
    {
        get
        {
            return _reader1RawCardData;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_reader1RawCardData != value)
            {
                _reader1RawCardData = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string Reader2RawCardData
    {
        get
        {
            return _reader2RawCardData;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_reader2RawCardData != value)
            {
                _reader2RawCardData = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public int Reader1BitsCount
    {
        get
        {
            return _reader1BitsCount;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_reader1BitsCount != value)
            {
                _reader1BitsCount = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public int Reader2BitsCount
    {
        get
        {
            return _reader2BitsCount;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_reader2BitsCount != value)
            {
                _reader2BitsCount = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public ICommand RefreshSourceCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(RefreshUnitStore);
        }
    }

    public ICommand SendReaderCardSwipeCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(SendReaderCardSwipe);
        }
    }

    public ICommand UpdateSelectedUnitConnectionStateCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(UpdateSelectedUnitConnectionState);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ItemsControl` is bound to `SelectedUnit.LocalControllerInfo.Inputs`. What is the type of `.Inputs`?

As written your bindings will not have access to `InputState` or `InputName`. That's not really in the scope of "how to identify what array item goes with what enum"

To address your original issue, one possibility would be to nest some tuples and bind to that, a la

```
List<Tuple<int,State>> States = new List<Tuple<int,State>>();

States.Add(new Tuple<int, State>(1,State.Bar));
States.Add(new Tuple<int, State>(2, State.Foo));
States.Add(new Tuple<int, State>(3, State.Bar));
```